# CAST BIGINT or LPAD for large numeric code

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, casting

I am working in pySpark and need to join two tables considering a numeric code of 14 characters.
This numeric code has a format of 01111111000111, in which is common to have Zero as the first character in the code.

The problem is that one table has this code as String and have this initial zero, but the other has this code as a number and doesn't have the initial zero.

So I have two possible solutions to perform the join:

- Cast the first table to BIGINT.
- Cast the second to String and apply LPAD to it.

The question is: which solution has a better performance?

Comment: There are different opinions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904179/why-is-integer-comparison-faster-then-string-comparison, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490477/performance-compare-string-vs-convert-to-int, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503735/is-number-comparison-faster-than-string-comparison

Comment: Thank you for the links. It's nice to see that string comparison is slower than integer comparison, and that the casting to integer is also slow.